# Unresolved externals when compiling code which uses a dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to get started on using dll's for my code in VS 2005.  The code I have is very simple, just to try a test case.

testdll.h:

```
#ifdef TEST_EXPORTS
#define TESTDLLPORT   __declspec( dllexport )
#else
#define TESTDLLPORT   __declspec( dllimport )
#endif

namespace TestDLLNS
{
    static int s = 0;
    class MyTestDll {
    public:
        static TESTDLLPORT int printDLLFuncs();
    };
}
```

testdll.cpp:

```
// testdll.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "testdll.h"

#ifdef _MANAGED
#pragma managed(push, off)
#endif

namespace TestDLLNS {
    int MyTestDll::printDLLFuncs() {
        cout << "DLL function called" << endl;
        return s;
    }
}
#ifdef _MANAGED
#pragma managed(pop)
#endif
```

test.cpp:

```
// test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "testdll.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "int: " << TestDLLNS::MyTestDll::printDLLFuncs() << endl;
    cout << "Called dll" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static int _*cdecl TestDLLNS::MyTestDll::printDLLFuncs(void)" (*_imp_?printDLLFuncs@MyTestDll@TestDLLNS@@SAHXZ) referenced in function _main   test.obj

dumpbin \exports testdllD.dll gives the following:
    ordinal hint RVA      name

```
      1    0 0001105F ?printDLLFuncs@MyTestDll@TestDLLNS@@SAHXZ
```

So the symbol clearly exists in the .dll.  Should Visual Studio also be creating a testdllD.lib files which I should be linking with test.cpp?  If so, how I  get visual studio to make both a .dll and a .lib.

Edit: Am I doing the importing/exporting correctly?  From what I understand, whem compiling the dll you would want to use dllexport while when compiling the executable which uses the dll, dllimport would be used.

Comment: Do you have the TestDll project and the Test project in one solution?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same solution and they share the same output debug directory.

Comment: When both projects are in one solution you don't need to fiddle with library path. You can set Project dependency that will do this job for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things to note and I hope you did not miss them.

1. What you have is a linking error, means that your compiling was okay, but there is a link error. The error shows that the linking does not find a definition for your printDLLFuncs() function which was referenced in the object file.
2. You either have to provide the path for the .lib file where the function is defined in the Project Directories -> library path, or put it in any of the project folders so your Visual Studio can find it.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't seem to create a testdll.lib when I build testdll.  Is there any way to create this .lib without causing my test application statically link to the .lib?

Comment: Wow! Thats some comment. okay now, did you tell Visual Studio to create it? It did not create even after you told that you want one to call your functions and that you don't like Link errors? I think you ground Visual Studio for a week. What do you say my friend?


Ok, jokes apart, what kind of project are you building? Win32 DLL project? You must have a .lib with the same name as your dll in the output directory. Please check there.

Comment: Configuration Type: Dynamic Library (.dll)

The output directory only creates a .dll, when I tell it to compile the .lib (via changing the configuration to "Static Library) and point the linker of test to that directory, I still have the same unresolved symbol error.

Comment: @Christopher: There is difference between creating static and dynamic libraries and the ways to use them. Can you tell how did you create this DLL project?

Comment: I created a dynamic dll. You were right about the library path. It was outputing the .lib file to another location and once I linked to that location the test project linked properly and worked.

Comment: @Christopher: Great, there you go!